# How long does ga() take to complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

In my ajax call of log in page, if it returns a param named is_first_login = 1, then I need to call ga() to send GA event.

And immediately after that, the page is redirected to main dashboard page.
But not sure why, ga() is not fired sometimes.

How long does GA event firing takes to complete in average?

```
  // Make ajax call for login.
  fn._post('user.post_login', {
    username: username,
    pwd: pwd,
    redirect_to: redirect_to,
  }, function (json) {

    if ( !json.error && json.is_first_login ) {

      if (typeof ga !== 'undefined') {
        var event_category = 'Subscribe - First Login',
            event_action = 'First Login',
            event_label = 'Partner';

        ga('send', 'event', event_category, event_action, event_label);
        ga('newTracker.send', 'event', event_category, event_action, event_label);
      }
    }

    if (json.redirect) {
      fn._redirect(json.redirect);
      return;
    }

    $('.msg').remove();
    if (json.error) {
      fn._inlineMsg(jUsername.parent(), json.msg);
      jUsername.focus();
      jLoginBtn.parent().removeClass('loading');
    }
  });
```

Comment: Shure. It has to ping the google servers... Thats how it works...

Comment: Strange question. Even in quantum computing and high speed networks stuff takes a time to complete that's greater than zero. I suppose you actually want to know if browser aborts pending AJAX requests on page unload...

Comment: @Alvaro Just changed. Thank you for your kind teaching that it is quantum computing network. I didn't know :D

Comment: Here's an [interesting article](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/async-analytics-snippet) about google analytics snippet performance, and optimizations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can never tell how long the tracking request is going to take on the client's computer. My tracking requests take usually arround 25ms (rarely it took much more - like 960ms).

You can test it yourself. Just run following from your browsers console:

```
var start = (new Date()).getTime();
ga('send', 'event', 'event_category', 'event_action', 'event_label', {
    hitCallback: function() {
      console.log("Tracking took " + ((new Date()).getTime() - start));
    }
});
```

However, the time you get is just informative and you can't rely on it. On some other client's computer may get different response times.

Therefore you might want to put your redirection code inside a callback function.

```
setTimeout(function(){
  //redirect here
}, 2000);

ga('send', 'event', event_category, event_action, event_label, {
  hitCallback: function() {
    //redirect here
  }
});
```

The *setTimeout* is used just in case, the *hitCallback* never happens (which is also possible).

Read more on https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/sending-hits#knowing_when_the_hit_has_been_sent

Do not forget to call *event.preventDefault()* when binding tracking code onto element that does redirect by default (eg *<a>, <button>* ...)

Answer (score -1):

`ga()` queues the analytics request, mainly to wait for the full analytics library to download.  (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/command-queue-reference)

If you are redirecting before that resource loads, then the call out to google analytics will not be made.

Comment: analytics.js was already fully loaded before this event is fired. I'd like to know how long it would take to complete  ga('send')  call.

Comment: it depends on the server response time, and it can differ. You should write a callback function with a set timeout-function. 1 sec should be enough time for ga to send a callback. The timeout is to make your scipt not depend on ga. It proceeds if ga is not responding, just in case.